# Is it possible to build a infinite scroll experience with the repeater field in the Advance Custom Field plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering if it's possible when you have for an example 30 items in the ACF repeater to display only 10 items on page load and load additional 10 items each time when scroll positions has moved to the bottom?

Comment: What did you researched about it?

Comment: I see that you can fetch the first row here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/ So I guess it would be easy to check how many items there are and display the first items.

Comment: @Ingvi Did you found a way for such a build?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible, but not out of the box with Advanced Custom Fields.
I released an [extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more-for-acf/) for [Ajax Load More](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) that could help you... It can handle infinite scrolling repeater, flexible content and gallery field types.